# How to reverse a linked list in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linked-list

In the mutation example below, I don't understand how the linked list is reversed.

```
class LinkedListNode
  attr_accessor :value, :next_node

  def initialize(value, next_node=nil)
    @value = value
    @next_node = next_node
  end
end

def print_values(list_node)
  print "#{list_node.value} --> "
  if list_node.next_node.nil?
    print "nil\n"
    return
  else
    print_values(list_node.next_node)
  end
end
def reverse_list(list, previous=nil)
  current_head = list.next_node
  list.next_node = previous
  if current_head
    reverse_list(current_head, list)
  else
    list
  end
end

node1 = LinkedListNode.new(37)
node2 = LinkedListNode.new(99, node1)
node3 = LinkedListNode.new(12, node2)
print_values(node3)
puts "-------"
revlist = reverse_list(node3)
print_values(revlist)
```

If I just return `current_head`, I get `99->37->nil`, which makes sense because `99` would be `next_node`. Returning the next line,

```
list.next_node = previous
```

throws an error because `print_values` method can't print the value for `nil`. I'm not understanding what is reversing the list. If anyone could explain this to me, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Just run the algorithm manually. With pen and paper. Tracing states of nodes. You'll see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a little visualization I made up.

`^` points to head of the list. At each level of recursion, its right arrow is "turned" to point from element on the right to element on the left. Proceed until there is a right arrow (pointing to a non-nil). If right arrow points to nil, return the current head.

```
previous
↓
nil    12 -> 99 -> 37 -> nil
       ^

       previous
       ↓ 
nil <- 12       99 -> 37 -> nil
                ^

             previous
             ↓
nil <- 12 <- 99       37 -> nil
                      ^         

nil <- 12 <- 99 <- 37 
                   ^
```

Comment: Anthony, did it help? :) Now do you see what's happening there?

Comment: Great visualization, it wasn't so much that I didn't understand how the pointers were being rearranged, I didn't understand what the reverse_list code was doing. You both gave great answers! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Seeing your answer while reading through Pierres answer really helped. Once I understood it I decided to try an iterative solution instead of recursion, just to solidify things.

Answer (score 3):

```
# Create a LinkedListNode instance with value 36
node1 = LinkedListNode.new(37)
# Create a LinkedListNode instance which next value is node1
node2 = LinkedListNode.new(99, node1)
# node2 -> node1
# Create a LinkedListNode instance which next value is node2
node3 = LinkedListNode.new(12, node2)
# node3 -> node2 -> node1

print_values(node3)
# 12 -> 99 -> 37
```

Fist pass into reverse_list method

```
reverse_list(node3)
def reverse_list(list, previous=nil)
  # set current_head to node2
  current_head = list.next_node
  # Change node3.next_node node2-->nil
  list.next_node = previous
  if current_head
    # reverse_list(node2, node3)
    reverse_list(current_head, list)
  else
    list
  end
end
```

Second pass into reverse_list method

```
reverse_list(node2, node3)
def reverse_list(list, previous=nil)
  # set current_head to node1
  current_head = list.next_node
  # Change node2.next_node node1-->node3
  list.next_node = previous
  if current_head
    # reverse_list(node1, node2)
    reverse_list(current_head, list)
  else
    list
  end
end
```

last pass into reverse_list method

```
reverse_list(node1, node2)
def reverse_list(list, previous=nil)
  # set current_head to nil
  current_head = list.next_node
  # Change node1.next_node nil-->node2
  list.next_node = previous
  if current_head
    reverse_list(current_head, list)
  else
    # The end, return node1
    list
  end
end
```

By the way linked list is not a common practice in the ruby languages (and all the languages with a garbage collector), there is generally a class (such as Array for example) which have all the functionalities and flexibility you may need.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, does it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  Do you ever sleep?

Comment: @WandMaker: I was about to :)

Comment: you're right, it doesn't. I had not correctly understood the question

Comment: Yes, I understand. I'm only doing it because I have to, its part of the course I'm taking. They even told us its never rarely used, but important to understand because its a common interview question.

Comment: It took me time, but I edited my comment. As you see I just explains what does each iteration does. I don't see a clearer way to explain it.

Comment: @PierreMichard: check out my explanation :)

Comment: nice, I have been searching an elegant way of explaining that. You clearly found the way :)

Comment: Thanks, Pierre! Great answer!

Comment: You're welcome. Tell you teacher to create a Class for Ruby instead of adapting a C class to Ruby :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution if someone is looking to do this without recursion

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :next

  def initialize(value, next_node)
    @value = value
    @next = next_node
  end
end

class LinkedList
  attr_accessor :head, :tail

  def add(value)
    if(@head.nil?)
      @head = Node.new(value, nil)
      @tail = @head
    else
      @tail.next = Node.new(value, nil)
      @tail = @tail.next
    end
  end

  def reverse(list)
    return nil if list.nil?
    prev = nil
    curr = list.head

    while(curr != nil)
      temp = curr.next
      curr.next = prev
      prev = curr
      curr = temp
    end
    list.head = prev
    list
  end

  def display(list)
    return nil if list.nil?
    curr = list.head
    arr = []
    while(curr != nil)
      arr.push(curr.value)
      curr = curr.next
    end
    p arr
  end
end

list = LinkedList.new()
list.add(1)
list.add(2)
list.add(3)

list.display(list)                #list before reversing [1,2,3]
list.display(list.reverse(list))  #list after reversing  [3,2,1]
```